# Unable to resolve Host for android App why?

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, hosting, web-hosting

I have developed an android native app with a backend in MYSQL. While Had a proper internet connection I got an issue which is when I was trying to log-in to the app I got an error toast as "Volley connection Error: Unable to resolve host of my hosting server in the phones which are in above API 27 version. But It works without the mentioned issue up to API 27 version android phones.
Why I got this issue??

[image: Error msg]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.MySQL"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
  //  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

  


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in application tag of android manifest file.

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" 
    >

</application>
```